# how to extend an entity from one bundle to another bundle

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, bundle

i have an already created symfony bundle. i wanted to add another bundle for my application separately. so now im facing a problem that how to extend an entity from old bundle to newly created one. i extended it normally but it giving errors.

i have these 2 bundles,

```
MyFirstBundle
MySecondBundle
```

MyFirstBundle entity,

```
namespace My\FirstBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="companies")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 */
class Company
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @Groups({"list_companies", "company_details", "ad_details"})
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)'
     *
     * @Groups({"ad_details"})
     */
     private $name;
```

MySecondBundle Entity,

```
namespace My\SecondBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use My\FirstBundle\Entity\Company as BaseCompany;

class Companies extends BaseCompany 
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

im not sure that i can extend my entity like this. im getting error when creating forms with this entity

```
Class "MySecondBundle:companies" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the doctrine annotations for the second entity as well.

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="companies")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 */
class Companies extends BaseCompany 
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```